# createrawtransaction using json rpc

Tags: json, json-rpc, bitcoin

I'm trying to make a raw transaction using bitcoind using -
json-rpc over http post -

```
{'jsonrpc': '1.0', 'id':'rqid4027056','method': 'createrawtransaction', 'params': [{'txid':'2ad8f232b833cf13512ce6f7eb208883a0b07e5ef7318e0f2d2df38b0f26c98a','vout':1}],{'1FaFRYxY8baVNfjxz67nDGxcKvuSFuUcav':0.00032345}}
```

Is this format correct  ?

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out. I have spent hours trying to do this with no luck..

Answer (score 2):

The parameter of params  is an array of array and a object.

```
    'params': [[{'txid':'2ad8f232b833cf13512ce6f7eb208883a0b07e5ef7318e0f2d2df38b0f26c98a',
'vout':1}],{'1FaFRYxY8baVNfjxz67nDGxcKvuSFuUcav':0.00032345}]
```

Try something like above, I am unable to test it at the moment.
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON should use double-quotes for strings, as that is standard.

Your current JSON also terminates the `params` array early, since you have `'params':[{'txid':'...'}]`:
[image: Early termination of params array]

Your JSON should look something like this:
[image]

Here's that JSON flattened out:

```
{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"rqid4027056","method":"createrawtransaction","params":[[{"txid":"2ad8f232b833cf13512ce6f7eb208883a0b07e5ef7318e0f2d2df38b0f26c98a","vout":1}],{"data":"16ae4544b56c619e5624fa708c3b1887e785baa3e338be5c805ba3b39d0427e1","1FaFRYxY8baVNfjxz67nDGxcKvuSFuUcav":0.00032345}]}
```

That should give you the following response:

```
{"result":"01000000018ac9260f8bf32d2d0f8e31f75e7eb0a0838820ebf7e62c5113cf33b832f2d82a0100000000ffffffff020000000000000000226a2016ae4544b56c619e5624fa708c3b1887e785baa3e338be5c805ba3b39d0427e1597e0000000000001976a9149fdb87156b23dc5eec639b2d730f325353f628a088ac00000000","error":null,"id":"1"}
```

That's the same result you'd get from running the following with the reference bitcoin-rpc client:

```
createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"2ad8f232b833cf13512ce6f7eb208883a0b07e5ef7318e0f2d2df38b0f26c98a","vout":1}]' '{"data":"16ae4544b56c619e5624fa708c3b1887e785baa3e338be5c805ba3b39d0427e1","1FaFRYxY8baVNfjxz67nDGxcKvuSFuUcav":0.009}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure it out, yet?  I'm looking, too.  I think params needs to be an array...

```
{'jsonrpc': '1.0', 'id':'rqid4027056','method': 'createrawtransaction', 'params': [[{'txid':'2ad8f232b833cf13512ce6f7eb208883a0b07e5ef7318e0f2d2df38b0f26c98a','vout':1}],{'1FaFRYxY8baVNfjxz67nDGxcKvuSFuUcav':0.00032345}]}
```